# Query with error ORA-01843: not a valid month, with data of type DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, types

I'm trying to make a query in an oracle bank, but in the field "data_exportacao" I find this error - ORA-01843: not a valid month -

I did a little research but I only found references to data conversion that are in timestemp to DATE, but my values ​​in the bank are not as timestemp, they are as DATE.

I am new to Oracle and databases, and there is little reference in my native language, thanks for your patience.

```
SELECT
      *
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          COALESCE(TIPO, 'SOMA') AS "TIPO",
          COUNT(*) AS "QUANTIDADE",
          COALESCE(CAST(TRUNC(DATA_EXPORTACAO) AS VARCHAR(50)), 'TOTAL------------->') AS "DATA CRIAÇÃO"
        FROM
          WORKORDER
        WHERE
          DATA_EXPORTACAO BETWEEN '14/09/20' AND '19/09/20'
        AND TIPO IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY GROUPING SETS 
        (
          (TIPO, DATA_EXPORTACAO),
          (TIPO),
          (DATA_EXPORTACAO),
          ()      
        )
       )
      PIVOT ( SUM(QUANTIDADE) FOR (TIPO) IN ('INSP', 'INSP15KV', 'PJ', 'AC', 'INSPLINHAS', 'INSPSE', 'OE', 'INSPPROTEC', 'SOMA' ) )
      ORDER BY 1;
```

I would like to form a report with this data, work carried out in a certain period of time.

I attached evidence of errors, and comparisons of the data accessed in my application and in Dbeaver

Comment: And just as a side observation <getting on soapbox> PLEASE use 4-digit years. Always.  Every time.   Ever hear of something called "the Y2k bug"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce `date` constants using the `date` keyword and YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
DATA_EXPORTACAO BETWEEN DATE '2020-09-14' and DATE '2020-09-19'
```

Note that in Oracle, the `DATE` data type -- despite its name -- also stores a time component.  For this reason, I strongly discourage using `BETWEEN`.  Instead:

```
DATA_EXPORTACAO >= DATE '2020-09-14' AND
DATA_EXPORTACAO < DATE '2020-09-20'
```

This works regardless of whether there is a time component.

Comment: @LucasRicardo - Both of Gordon's recommendations are excellent: use the `date` literal syntax, and use `>=` and `<` rather than `between`. Back to your attempt though: you were using strings like `'14/09/20'` and expected Oracle to view them as dates. Oracle needs to know the format, and if you don't specify it, it uses the `nls_date_format` session parameter, which is - obviously - not `dd/mm/yy` in your session. To correct that, you must use the `to_date()` function and give the format model: `to_date('14/09/20', 'dd/mm/yy')`.

Comment: @LucasRicardo - `to_date()` is especially important if the date itself (in string data type) is data stored in a table, or if it is computed with string functions in the query itself, etc.; in that case you can't use the `date` literal. If you have a hard-coded date as you have in your query, use the `date` literal as in Gordon's answer.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the explanations, I was trying to solve this for a while, what confused me is that I was able to return the search values ​​using to_date () in a bank manager that I have, Dbeaver, already in my application that uses cx_Oracle 8.0 .1 next to his instant client, I couldn't, I thought it was bank driver problems, both search a remote database.

I am grateful for the knowledge, hugs from Brazil!